# Convolutional Auto Encoder Decoder error in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

I'm attempting to train a convolutional auto-encoder to recreate images that are 80X130

I've added all the necessary imports, and I'm writing it in python 3.7

This is the error I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "CAED_Keras.py", line 52, in ", line 52, in 
>       validation_data=(x_train, x_train))                                   , in fit
>
> File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1154, in fit                                                                   in _standardize_user_data
>       batch_size=batch_size)
>
> File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 621,e 145, in standardize_input_data in _standardize_user_data
>       exception_prefix='target')                                            , 76, 1) but got array with shape (1, 80, 130)
>
> File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 145, in standardize_input_data
>               str(data_shape))
>
> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_7 to have shape (4, 76, 1) but got array with 
>       shape (1, 80, 130)

Here is my code:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(80, 130, 1)) 

x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

#Load Data
x_train = np.copy(lt.mel_spect_out[:int(len(lt.mel_spect_out)/10*9)])
x_test = np.copy(lt.mel_spect_out[int(len(lt.mel_spect_out)/10*9):])

#normalize
x_train = x_train / 255.
x_test = x_test / 255.


x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 80, 130, 1))  
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 80, 130, 1))  

autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
            epochs=50,
            batch_size=30,
            shuffle=True,
            validation_data=(x_train, x_train))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems:

### The network's architecture

I changed a few things: first, I added an UpSampling layer after the encoded one and removed the final one to conserve symmetry. Then, I added `padding='same'` to the last 16-filters conv layer to prevent your data from being "cropped".

Here is the resulting code:

```
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(encoded)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
```

### The input shape

The problem here is that you want to downsample your data 3 times.

No problem for the first dimension: `80 % 2^3 = 0`.

But for the second one: `130 % 2^3 = 2`, this is problematic.

**What can you do?**

- You could crop your images' heights to 128
- I have no other idea at the moment

### One last note

You used

```
validation_data=(x_train, x_train)
```

Comment: After adjusting the image size to 80x128 I get the error -> "Error when checking target: expected conv2d_7 to have shape (76, 124, 1) but got array with shape (80, 128, 1)"

Comment: Did you also set `padding='same'` to the last 16-filters conv layer? I tested it on my machine, it is working well.